# Can we create our own stack data structure implementation with out array or List in java?

Tags: java, data-structures

I had been asked a question in interview as below.

Can we implement our own  Stack Data structure without using arrays or lists or even node types.

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes. In fact, Java has a [`Stack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html). What have you tried?

Comment: Sure you can use any class for datastructures. In most cases you will just need to add some pointers to other elements.

Comment: Yes, but it would be a linked list at it's core...

Comment: This seems like it would work a lot better on [CS.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/), honestly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the call stack, but that wouldn't be useful in most scenarios.

Suppose you have an interactive application in which the user can choose to push or pop elements.

You'll have a method with a single local variable that holds the top element of the stack.

That method will ask the user to choose whether to pop the last element or push a new element.

If the user chooses push, the method will make a recursive call to itself, passing the pushed element as argument (which would be stored in the local variable of the called method).

If the user chooses pop, the method will return its local variable to the calling method.

Here's some pseudo code :

```
public static Object stack (Object element)
{
    Object top = element;

    int input = 0;
    while (input != 2) {
        input = ... // get user input - 1 for push 2 for pop
        if (input == 1) {
            Object newElement = ... // get input from user
            Object poppedElement = stack (newElement); // push the new element
        } 
    }
    return top; // pop the top of the stack
}
```

Comment: "public static Object stack (Object element)" this would be the correct signature of the method.

But this implementation would hold only one element, or am I missing something?

Comment: @aurelianus I said it was pdeudo code :) fixed the return type. It can hold as many elements as there is room in the call stack for recursive calls to the stack method. If the user types 1 and inputs a new element, and repeat the process 10 times, `stack` is called 10 times recursively, and the local variable in each one of them holds a different element.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you cannot use any collection or array, you can use a file, and each line of that file can be an element pushed to the stack (the file), And giving the principle of the stack LIFO, than the first line of the text file would need to be retrieve at pop, or the pushed element will be added in the first line of the text file.

Comment: you are most welcomed!